# Definir método dentro do corpo de um outo método em Java

Tags: java, método

Olá, estava pesquisando sobre Java e me deparei com o seguinte código:

```
cliente.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()
```

Não entendi muito bem. Isso é um método dentro de outro método? Tentei fazer:

```
public class Post {
    public void Post(){
        public void test(){}
    }
}
```

Mas o NetBeans acusa que o código está errado. Bom, gostaria de saber como isso funciona (se pudessem implementar um código simples de exemplo)

[Link do codigo que eu achei](http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/apendice-sockets/#19-5-servidor)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Na linha

```
cliente.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()
```

Primeiro a variável cliente tem esse método `getInetAdress()`, ele um outro objeto que por sua vez tem outro método `getHostAdress()`

O termo técnico é *chaining* - chamada encadeada

**Um exemplo seria:**

```
public class Pessoa{

    private Date dataNascimento = new Date();

    public Date getDataNascimento(){
        return dataNascimento;
    }
}



public class Main{
   public static void main(String... args){
   Pessoa p =new Pessoa();
   System.out.println(p.getDataNascimento().toString())
   }

}
```

Assim, no código acima eu chamo um método `toString()` a partir do Objeto `Date` retornado da classe Pessoa. O método `toString()` é definido na classe Date, e não na classe pessoa:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html